# Fluxbox remove toolbar

Tags: cairo-dock, fluxbox

I have setup a minimal desktop with `cairo-dock` and `fluxbox` but now the cairo-dock has the fuunctionalliy of the toolbar therefore the toolbar itself seems useless to me.

So how can I remove completely the fluxbox's toolbar and use only `cairo-dock`?

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=40637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Panther mentions is to run the command:

```
nano ~/.fluxbox/init
```

Then over the file change the following (search by pressing `Ctrl`+`W`):

```
session.screen0.toolbar.tools:  prevworkspace, workspacename, nextworkspace, clock, prevwindow, nextwindow, iconbar            
session.screen0.toolbar.autoHide:       false
session.screen0.toolbar.visible:        false
```

Note:
As you saw over the `session.screen0.toolbar.tools:` setting just remove the `systemtray` option ;)